# Control UX to create pre formed responses easily

Tags: tree, reports

I need to build a component to help doctors generate patient reports after they run a test. The goal is to optimize the time taken to generate these reports. Currently they take upwards of 30m to produce.

I've attached an example report below. The data like date, patient name, measurements etc, are sourced from some metadata that comes out of a machine. The area I am unsure about is the Comments and the Conclusions sections. I have highlighted 2 canned responses under Left Atrium, but almost every bit of text under Comments is generated.

[image: Example report]

Every bit of text in the Comments section are preformed observation phrases, that depends on the measurement values. They don't want to write this text manually - they want to select from a dropdown, or auto complete, or some other control. I would estimate for each section (Left Ventricle, Atrium, etc), there are ~ 100 pre canned responses that the doctor selects from. In 95% of studies, it's a select few responses that are used (i.e. most people don't have some specific condition). They want to minimize manual typing of these responses, which is what they do currently.

My current thinking is to have an inline editing page, where they click on the fields and edit the report, in a WYSIWYG style. For the Comments and Conclusions section, I was thinking a tree view type selector [like this one.](https://github.com/dowjones/react-dropdown-tree-select) But I worry this will be clunky with too many responses to choose from.

Does anyone have any other ideas? What is this pattern called?

Comment: Are you doctors familiar with the pre-filled comments? For example, would they be aware of keywords within each of the comments enabling them to find a comment they wanted?

Comment: Also, will each comment category have a comment or could come be left blank?

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend a type-ahead search if your users are familiar with the results and could be reasonably expected to know what they are searching for.

The reason this works is because the results are narrowed by the keywords entered, and are trimmed as more keywords are added, so your 100+ results are trimmed pretty quickly.

This won't work if your users are not familiar with the expected results and we'd have to revisit it.

Then adding them to the notes is achieved by simply clicking the plus next to the comment, clicking it again to remove it. I haven't mocked the final screen which shows the comments added but I'm sure you could style something up.

Any Q's please come back to me.

[image]

Comment: Good call. A couple of extra thoughts: 1) This can be very fast if you have keyboard navigation to highlight and select the suggested results. The user can type, hit [down], [down], [enter] and then start on their next selection. 2) This is also works well when you need the user to be able to add their own response manually - if they type far enough that there are no suggestions, the results list can change to a "New response" indicator. 2a) It can be handy to allow the user to save their new response for future use, too.

Comment: This is fantastic. Give me a day or so to digest and think about how I could make this work